# How to avoid chrome extensions from closing on clicking elsewhere

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am developing a chrome extension and I want to know that is there a function/way that allows me to type and also select text and the extension should stay open? Normally when I Use the extension popup and I Click outside the extension close. Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard popup can't do that so you'll have to insert a DOM element with your UI into the current web page. This is often achieved via an iframe + web_accessible_resources.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to some resource, it would be very helpful